# ssh-copy-id hangs with 8192-bit key

Tags: ssh, osx, openindiana

Having a bit of an issue with *ssh-copy-id* it seems to hang when i try to copy *8192-bit rsa* keys accross to an **OpenIndiana** server. I running **OS X** as my client OS. Is anyone aware of issues with keys of this size?

Comment: Have you attempted the connection turning up the debugging via `ssh -vvv`?

Comment: Works for me with an 8192 bit key and Linux client and server: `OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012`.

Comment: For completeness, I tested with a 16384 bit key (the max key size for my version of ssh) and it worked fine too. Took a long time (5 minutes or so) to create that 16384 bit key and has a noticeable 2 or 3 second delay when authenticating to the remote host.